# What options are available for file:// in the Firefox address bar?

Tags: firefox, browser, address-bar

Can I narrow the results of the `file://` entry in the Firefox address bar? More specifically, can I add wildcards and/or filetypes?

I'd like to have the same ability as Windows Explorer in my browser.

Comment: Uhm, no you can't? Firefox is a web browser, not a file system browser. Firefox can only open files it is supposed to, after all, it's a web browser. Wildcards? What for, exactly? Which functionality or which use case are you after?

Comment: I type a search directly into the address bar of Windows Explorer and it tries to open it as a webpage?  Does Windows Explorer even have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding wildcards, you can do something like:

`file://localhost/`

or instead do:

`file://localh*st/`

and get the same results. I'm not sure that's all that helpful however.